# Revoke permission from the permission list issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

After revoking permission from the permission list the app won't restart.
I read that after revoking permission from the list the app process been terminate.
Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: *Can anyone confirm this?* - yes, you can. Revoke the permission and see what happens. It's not hard.

Comment: It is possible to make the app restart after revoke permission by itself?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you go to setting and revoke permissions of an app, the app just lost focus and also in background, you could see it in recent apps list.

When you finish revoking and return to the app, it comes to foreground and corresponding life cycle callback would be triggered. And if the app need these permissions to run, but which be revoked by user, the app should run abnormally!

Comment: That's incorrect. There may be a _screenshot_ of the app in the recents list, but it's no longer running. You can see this e.g. by looking at the running activities with `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`. Regarding _"if the app need these permissions to run, but which be revoked by user, the app should run abnormally"_ - an app should never assume that it still has a permission just because the permission was granted at some point in the past. It should always request the necessary permission right before performing the action that requires the permission.

Comment: Yes, after android 6.0, we should request permissions explicitly.